# Há diferença entre conectar ao banco usando uma classe e pelo visual studio: Tools>Conect_to_database?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

Estou aprendendo C# e gostaria de saber se há diferença entre os dois tipos de conexão citados no título. Se sim, quais?

Comment: Diferença em que sentido? Há muita ou nada.

Comment: Eu sou novo em C#, quero criar uma aplicação para que inclua/altere/atualize os dados no banco. Vi vários videos relativos a isso, em que se cria uma classe que faz essa conexão. Entretanto, há também essa outra opção. O que eu queria saber é se eu terei os mesmos resultados em ambos modos. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servem para coisas diferentes no Visual Studio ligas à base de dados para a criar e administrar(criar a lógica da base de dados como tabelas relações etc...). Na tua aplicação vais ligar para inserir e tratar os dados. A lógica será no VS crias a tabela e os seus campos... na aplicação inseres os dados fornecidos pelo utilizador na base de dados respeitando a estrutura que criaste no VS.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, depende de como você projeta sua aplicação. Eu estou trabalhando uma aplicação C# Winforms e estou usando a metodologia Code First. Assim sendo, todo processo de conexão é feito via código. Não possuo objetos visuais conectados. Se você for desenvolver estilo Delphi, pode conectar via objetos na tela de design, porém não tenho experiência com este modo.

Não sei quem deu -1 na sua pergunta, achei desnecessário, visto que é uma dúvida de iniciante.

Comment: Obrigado, amigo! Também não entendi essa revolta com minha pergunta rs, mas tudo bem.. vlw!

Comment: tranquilo, se for começar algo novo, use code first. É bem melhor e mais fácil de entender o sistema.